# MySQL> User Defined Variable that uses DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

We are trying to define a user-defined variable that can be used in multiple queries.  Let us assume we have a column called `name` in table `MyDB.myTable`.  We are able to define the following user-defined variable without any issues:

```
SELECT @name_list_all := name FROM MyDB.myTable;
```

However, attempting to define the following user-defined variable:

```
SELECT @name_list_uniq := DISTINCT name FROM MyDB.myTable;
```

gives `ERROR 1064 (42000)`

---

**Addendum:**
`SELECT DISTINCT`, as suggested by **@jarlh**, works but I am having trouble using the user-defined variable with the `IN` clause, for example

```
SELECT blah-blah-blah WHERE name IN (@name_list_uniq);
```

returns Empty Set.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: cool story bruh. was there a ***question*** ?  (Were you meaning to ask for other examples of invalid syntax that will also return error 1064 ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list, you need some sort of aggregation.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT @name_list_uniq := GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name)
FROM MyDB.myTable;
```

That said, I strongly discourage what you are attempting to do.  If you need the names in your table, *use the table*.

Answer (score 0):

**Cannot**

An `@variable` cannot hold an array of values.

**Temp table**

This would let you collect the list in a "temporary" table for use via `JOIN`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t AS
    SELECT
        DISTINCT           -- this will work in this context
        name FROM myTable;

SELECT ...
    FROM a
    JOIN b  ON a.name = b.name
    ...
```

**WITH clause**

`WITH` (MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2) is a variant on `TEMPORARY TABLE`.

**FIND_IN_SET**

With `GROUP_CONCAT`, you could collect the names in a string, then test with that string via `FIND_IN_SET()`.  (There are multiple caveats and restrictions.)